# Laravel -Trigger a controller method in x minutes within a code

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.4

In my controller method,

Once all the payment details are validated for format,

We initiate the payment.

Now, on initiation of this (and every other) payment, I need to schedule a Controller call in 15 min with parameters (payment gateway token) to check if the payment was completed..else dismiss it.

Now, I can use a cron every minute to check for payments made 15 minutes back. But running a one time scheduled call would put less effort and pressure on system than running a cron every minute endlessly.

I explored the options in laravel like queuing or task scheduling. But none of it is one-time call (task scheduling) or queuing in x minutes.

Is there something that I am missing or some feature in laravel on similar grounds for the given requirement?

Comment: Schedule Task every 15 minutes what's the problem ?

Comment: that wouldn't work.. in your case... say a scheduled task ran at 10am, I made a payment P1 at 10:10am. Now the next scheduled task ran at 10:15 am but could not pick P1 (since the 15min duration for P1 had not yet passed). Now the next scheduled task at 10:30 will run and pick P1. And it will be 20min since P1 had been in initiated state. Does not solve the purpose

Comment: Cant you call your function after the payment is done, also please paste some code

Comment: So, I think it's better for you to customize your process rather than task scheduling

Comment: I need to call the function... but after "X" minutes. I do not wish to call it rightaway. I have my method and code. But I need to figure out a way to call it/schedule it after 15 min.

Comment: calling function after payment is not the purpose... on initialization is the purpose...to track timeout of payment if connection is lost or user goes dormant

Comment: When you find payments added with in last 15 mins you want to call that function, Am I right ?

Comment: You can dispatch a delayed job using the [laravel queue system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#delayed-dispatching) (note it takes some setting up). Queuing does allow one time calls.

Comment: thanks apokryfos... thats a good possibility..i'll explore

Comment: If you're using Stripe - judging by the tag - you can use their [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to get notified about the payment outcome. Here's a [handy write up](https://www.masteringmodernpayments.com/stripe-webhook-event-cheatsheet) about the webhook lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally create a ValidatePaymentJob, which you call in your controller method like this:

```
public function validatePaymentDetails()
{

    //Logic for validation the payment details goes up here

    dispatch(new ValidatePaymentJob($all, $needed, $parameters))
        ->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(x));
}
```

Then in your ValidatePaymentJob you can make a call to your payment provider to check if the payment was successful or not. You could even pass your transaction object with it and set a succeeded property to true.

You can check out the docs for Jobs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues)